# Local Storage on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile, local-storage, pouchdb

I've developed a web app that needs to work on mobile devices offline.  I've looked into progressive web apps and I'm pretty excited by the trend.  Sadly, Apple still doesn't have working support, but it looks like that's changing https://cloudfour.com/thinks/apple-starts-work-on-progressive-web-apps/

Even though Apple devices don't support PWAs as Android does, it seems like certain features are already supported such as offline storage via IndexedDB(?).  Does anyone know if I can currently use IndexedDB via PouchDB (for instance) to save/retrieve data?  A link to a web app with this capability would be very helpful.

All I need to do for my app to function is to be able to open pdf's located on the local file system and update/retrieve data from a browser based db.   Hopefully this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a progressive web app is, yet you can definitly use PouchDB on apple devices.

The [pouch docs](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html#pouchdb_in_the_browser) (dating back to 2015) still say that there's no support for IndexedDB on iOS Safari as the implementation is too buggy. Back then you could use PouchDB via WebSQL on iOS.

Recent versions of iOS and Safari do support IndexedDB, see [the caniuse on IndexedDB](https://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb). So you should also be able to use PouchDB via IndexedDB.